# Where can I find a patent with the number ZL 2014 2 0446264.5?

Tags: patent-applications, china

Where can I find the patent for the Joda busbar raising frame automatic screw device? The patent number is ZL 2014 2 0446264.5. china patent

Comment: Doesn't seem like a valid format. I cannot find a country for which ZL stands for.

Comment: Can you atleast provide the title of invention and date. I m thinking its ZA or NL

Comment: I have had a guess at what the underlying question is, and tried to make this explicit in the question. But please feel free to re-clarify.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely Chinese utility model [CN203999849](https://www.google.co.nz/patents/CN203999849U). The number you refer to is the application number.

ZL (zhuānlì) refers to the granted version of an application number. So ZL 201420446264 is the granted utility model of application number 201420446264, which is utility model 203999849.

Comment: Wow, here take my upvote!

Comment: @ Maca. Nice...can u tel me how did u find out that...

Comment: @ASHUVERMA I have had some occasion in the past to work with Chinese applications, so I just happened to recognise the format of the number. The utility model number was just a Google Patents search based on the application number.

Comment: It might be nice to edit the question to remove the ambiguity.